# How to construct (key, value) list from parallelized list in scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and I have some questions about how it works.
I want to do the next thing : given list of values, I want to construct some imitation of dictionary in parallel, something like that: `(1,2,3,4) -> ((1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4) )`. I know that if we deal with parallelized collections we should use accumulators. So here is my attempt:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

class DictAccumulatorV2 extends AccumulatorV2[Int, ListBuffer[(Int, Int)]] {
  private var dict:ListBuffer[(Int, Int)]= new ListBuffer[(Int, Int)]

  def reset(): Unit = {
    dict.clear()
  }

  def add(v: Int): Unit = {
    dict.append((v, v))
  }
  def value():ListBuffer[(Int, Int)] = {
    return dict
  }
  def isZero(): Boolean = {
    return dict.isEmpty
  }
  def copy() : AccumulatorV2[Int, ListBuffer[(Int, Int)]] = {
    // I do not understand how to code it correctly
    return new DictAccumulatorV2
  }
  def merge(other:AccumulatorV2[Int, ListBuffer[(Int, Int)]]): Unit = {
    // I do not understand how to code it correctly without reinitializing dict from val to var
    dict = dict ++ other.value
  }
}
object FirstSparkApplication {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyFirstApp").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val accum = new DictAccumulatorV2()
    sc.register(accum, "mydictacc")
    val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
    var res = distData.map(x => accum.add(x))
    res.count()
    println(accum)
  }
}
```

So I wonder if I do it right or there are any mistakes.

In general I also have questions about how `sc.parallelize` works. Does it actually parallelize job on my machine or it's just fictional string of code? What should I put instead of `"local"` in `setMaster`? How can I see on which nodes is the task been performing? Is the task performed on the all of the nodes at the same time or there is some sequence?

Answer (score 1):

> (1,2,3,4) -> ((1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4) )

You can do this in Scala by doing

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4)
val dict = list.map(i => (i,i))
```

Spark Accumulators are used as a communication means from Spark executor to Driver.

If you want to do the above in Parallel, then you would construct an RDD out of this list and applying map transformation to it like shown above.

In spark shell it would look like

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4)
val listRDD = sc.parallelize(list)
val dictRDD = listRDD.map(i => (i,i))
```

> how sc.parallelize works
> It creates a distributed Dataset (RDD in spark terms) using the collection that you pass in to the function. [More information](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections).

It does parallelize your job.
If you are submitting your spark job to a cluster then you should be able to see a YARN application ID or URL after running spark-submit command.You can visit the YARN application URL and see how many executors are processing that distributed dataset and what sequence they are performed in.

> What should I put instead of "local" in setMaster

From the Spark documentation -
The master URL to connect to, such as "local" to run locally with one thread, "local[4]" to run locally with 4 cores, or "spark://master:7077" to run on a Spark standalone cluster.